# Is there any IRC Server / Demon with integrated "bouncer"?

Tags: server, irc, channel

I want to offer IRC service to other users on my local network.
I'd like to have persistent logs of all (or at least certain) channels and private messages that can be replayed by the client. The log capacity could be limited. I know this is usually handled by a bouncer.
I want this setup to work locally, even if the server uplink goes down, so I probably want to run my own IRC server.

Are there any IRC servers already support this?

Answer (score 0):

Having a common chat and pastebin on the local network is very useful.

I've been attempting this today. And after some tribulations I have success.

I've been running ircd-hybrid without any problems for a while, but conversation histories, as you know, are not saved.

You could use any bouncer but I'll demonstrate ZNC:

If you're running linux, run...

```
sudo apt-get install znc
```

once it's installed, run...

`znc --makeconf`

This generates a config file. When asked for a port number specify a free port. This is the one you will connect to from your client and should NOT be the same as you IRC daemons port.
Later on you will be asked to specify the server you want to connect to, this should be 127.0.0.1:.

Make sure you firewall allows the new port, and restart ircd:

`sudo service <your irc daemon> restart`

That's it. Unless you've set it's modes to +i, your bouncer should now be visible on the channels you've asked it to join.

For more info on ZNC:
http://wiki.znc.in/FAQ

Might help to talk to the IRC crew at #ircd-coders on irc.ircd-hybrid.org

and for ZNC people... #znc on chat.freenode.net